# Django - how to define a MySQL CHAR data type in models?

Tags: python, django

I use MySQL as the db backend in django, I want to define a MySQL `CHAR` data type. When i use `CharField`, it will be a `VARCHAR` data type.

```
c0 = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

How to define a MySQL `CHAR` data type in django models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to Manually Create It.

```
from django.db import models

class MytypeField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'CHAR'


class your_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    your_field_you_want_to_create_custom_type = MytypeField()
```

Try it and comment if it works.

Comment: I would like to know how to do in case MytypeField() needs 36 characters exactly